# Overparametrized Model

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, anova

I am trying to understand the concept of an overparametrized model:

If I am considering a one way model:

$$Y_{jk}=\mu + \alpha_j + \epsilon_{jk}$$

Where $\epsilon_{jk}\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Why is this model considered overparametrized and has no solutions, when estimating the maximum likelihood values.

Comment: For all $\mu = \mu^{(0)} + \epsilon$ we can let $\alpha_j = \alpha^{(0)}_j - \epsilon$. Any combination $(\mu^{(0)} + \epsilon, \alpha^{(0)}_j + \epsilon)$ is an equally good explanation of the data.

Comment: To obtain a unique solution you'll need to add some restrictions on the parameters.  Typical restrictions are dependent on the objective.  For example one might set $\mu=0$ or $\sum_j \alpha_j=0$ or $\alpha_1=0$.

Comment: @JimB I am trying to get a deeper understanding of an overparametrized problem. It is my understanding that an overparametrized model is one that has more parameters then equations to solve for them? How does this apply to this model?

Comment: @Mikal  Can you elaborate as to why that is the case?

Comment: This is related to identifiability; see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/209018/119261) answer. By introducing additional constraints on the parameters, you get a full rank model (identifiability is restored). And full rank model implies unique solution.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/257778/119261.